# How to return variable as an output from SQL server 2016 R services?

Tags: r, sql-server-2016

I have the following code

```sql
EXECUTE sp_execute_external_script
    @language = N'R',
    @script = N'

        table1 <- unserialize(Table1_Data)
        table2 <- unserialize(Table2_Data)
        df_1 <-merge(x=table1,y=table2,
              by=c("batchId","BatchTaskID"),all=TRUE)
        df_2 <- df_1 %>% filter(batchId == 5 & BatchTaskStatus == 'N') %>%
             arrange(desc(BatchTaskRunID))
        if(nrow(df_2) > 1){ 
        result = TRUE
        return(result)
            }
        else {
            result = FALSE
            return(result)
            }

        OutputDataSet <- result
    ',
    @params = N'@Table1_Data VARBINARY(MAX), @Table2_Data VARBINARY(MAX)',
    @Table1_Data = @Table1_Data,
    @Table2_Data = @Table2_Data
    WITH RESULT SETS (( INT ));
```

How to return just the flag value instead of entire data frame from OutputDataset?

Comment: I do not see the value of using R here. All that can be handled in pure SQL.

Comment: I also know that , but this is the requirement and i have to follow it

Comment: Do you know anyway to get ouput

Comment: What does script currently do? Return entire data frame including all cols? How does it output entire data frame when you assign it to `result`?

Comment: merges two data frame and some aggregate and order by and some filter, after that I check whether it has any data or not and return flag value

Comment: Then what do you mean *instead of entire data frame from OutputDataset*? By your code this should only be the *result* flag: `OutputDataSet <- result`.